# javafx clip mask using complex shape

Tags: java, javafx-2

I’m creating a simple javafx application. I just want to clip the image from within the region provided in between two concentric circle, which changes the center cordinate on mouse move, the cliped object appeared at the defined position initialy but it does not respond to mouse move. Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

My code is:

```
public DoubleProperty xCordinate;
public DoubleProperty yCordinate;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Group root = new Group();
    Image image = new Image(MyClass.class
            .getResource("Water lilies.jpg").toExternalForm());
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            Color.WHITE);
    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setImage(image);
    xCordinate = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100.0f);
    yCordinate = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100.0f);
    scene.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            xCordinate.set(event.getX());
            yCordinate.set(event.getY());
            System.out.println("xCordinate " + xCordinate + " yCordinate "
                    + yCordinate);
        }

    });

    Circle c1 = new Circle();
    c1.centerXProperty().bind(xCordinate);
    c1.centerYProperty().bind(yCordinate);
    c1.setRadius(50.0f);
    Circle c2 = new Circle();
    c2.centerXProperty().bind(xCordinate);
    c2.centerYProperty().bind(yCordinate);
    c2.setRadius(35.0f);

    Shape mask = Path.subtract(c1, c2);

    view.setClip(mask);
    root.getChildren().add(view);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the mask clip on every change of circles' positions. By the way nice app.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Image image = new Image(MyClass.class.getResource("Water lilies.jpg").toExternalForm());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Color.WHITE);
        final ImageView view = new ImageView();
        view.setImage(image);

        xCordinate = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100.0f);
        yCordinate = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100.0f);


        final Circle c1 = new Circle();
        c1.centerXProperty().bind(xCordinate);
        c1.centerYProperty().bind(yCordinate);
        c1.setRadius(50.0f);

        final Circle c2 = new Circle();
        c2.centerXProperty().bind(xCordinate);
        c2.centerYProperty().bind(yCordinate);
        c2.setRadius(35.0f);

        scene.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xCordinate.set(event.getX());
                yCordinate.set(event.getY());
                System.out.println("xCordinate " + xCordinate + " yCordinate " + yCordinate);
                // update mask clip
                Shape mask = Path.subtract(c1, c2);
                view.setClip(mask);
            }
        });

        Shape mask = Path.subtract(c1, c2);
        view.setClip(mask);

        root.getChildren().add(view);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```